# MySQL search comma separated value syntax

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I am using MySQL.  In one of my table attributes, I have a serial number description like  "SM,ST,SK" for one device.

When users enter SM or ST or SK, I want my query to return a result

My current query looks like that:

```
SELECT CONCAT(lvl1_id,',',lvl2_id)
FROM hier_menus
LEFT JOIN labels ON (hier_menus.id=label_id AND tbl=65 AND fld=2 AND lang_id=5)
WHERE
hm_type=13 AND lvl1_id=141 AND lvl2_id=id AND label='".addslashes($serial)."'";
```

It is only able to look at the first comma part of serial number column. When users enter ST, it will not return anything.

Is it possible to search the whole of the long string "SM,ST,SK" to return a matching row?

Comment: addslashes does not ensure user input data is escaped correctly

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> select find_in_set('SK', 'SM,ST,SK');
+-------------------------------+
| find_in_set('SK', 'SM,ST,SK') |
+-------------------------------+
|                             3 | 
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select find_in_set('SP', 'SM,ST,SK');
+-------------------------------+
| find_in_set('SP', 'SM,ST,SK') |
+-------------------------------+
|                             0 | 
+-------------------------------+
```

You are looking for find_in_set,
however, this is not an optimize solution

you should seek to normalize your serial number into another table,
where each SM,ST, and SK is stored as one row

another way is to convert the data type to [`set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html)

Comment: using find_in_set is a good solution for the problem but it's recommended to normalize your database for better usability,scalability and performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT ... WHERE FIND_IN_SET($serial, label)
```

and as ajreal's pointed out, don't use addslashes. use mysql_real_escape_string (or whatever your DB abstraction library provides). addslashes is hopelessly broken and WILL allow someone to attack your database with ease.